# How can I get the authenticated user name under Apache using plain HTTP authentication and PHP?

Tags: php, apache, authentication, http-authentication

First, let's get the security considerations out of the way. I'm using simple authentication under Apache for a one-off, internal use only, non-internet connected LAN, PHP web app.

How can get I the HTTP authenticated user name in PHP?

Comment: I've used this to display the username from basic authentication: $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I think that you are after this

```
$username = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
$password = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that you are after this

$username = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
$password = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];