# how to get logged in user's name from .htpasswd?

Tags: php, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I have a password protected directory with htaccess and htpasswd.

My `.htpasswd` file looks like this:

```
user1:passwordstring
user2:passwordstring
user3:passwordstring
```

When any of the user login successfully into the directory is there anyway I can get that user's name using php?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that I've understood the question correctly, your answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417/how-can-i-get-the-authenticated-user-name-under-apache-using-plain-http-authenti). More [reference](http://php.net/features.http-auth).

```
<?php
$username = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
$password = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];
?>
```